# iptables block access to port 8000 except from IP address

Tags: firewall, iptables

I've never used iptables, and the documentation online seems a bit opaque.

I'd like to block all requests to port 8000 on my server except those coming from a specific IP address. How do I do that using iptables?

Comment: // , Would you be so kind as to share a link to the opaque documentation?

Comment: I know this is an old question but please consider moving this question to ServerFault. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the iptables tag: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/). Please delete this.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

This question should be on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).  Nevertheless, the following should do the trick, assuming you're talking about TCP and the IP you want to allow is 1.2.3.4:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DROP
```

Comment: How would you go about reversing this ip/port restriction you've setup here? (in case I want to undo this in the future)

Comment: tester, to remove stuff, refer to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197405/iptables-remove-specific-rules

Comment: I know this is relatively old, and this totally nailed what i needed. And since the answer has been accepted anyways, how do you do the same thing with a specific IP range? Thanks! :)

Comment: @JiegoCordoviz You can add a mask to the source address: "-s 1.2.3.0/24" will accept from anything starting with "1.2.3.".  Search for "netmask calculator" if you have a range and want to work out a netmask.

Comment: why might this not be working?

Answer (score 19):

Another alternative is;

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -s ! 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```

I had similar issue that 3 bridged virtualmachine just need access eachother with different combination, so I have tested this command and it works well.

Edit**

> According to Fernando comment and this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/401198/how-to-negate-a-range-in-iptables) exclamation mark
>   (`!`) will be placed before than `-s` parameter:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 ! -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```

Comment: The exclamation point (`!`) must now be placed before the `-s` parameter: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -s ! 1.2.3.4 -j DROP`.

Comment: I'm not sure what does the exclamation mark do here. Is it any better than the accepted answer?

Comment: @aexl pretty much same thing except single line

Answer (score 7):

You can always use iptables to delete the rules.  If you have a lot of rules, just output them using the following command.

```
iptables-save > myfile
```

`vi` to edit them from the commend line.  Just use the "dd" to delete the lines you no longer want.

```
iptables-restore < myfile and you're good to go.
```

REMEMBER THAT IF YOU DON'T CONFIGURE YOUR OS TO SAVE THE RULES TO A FILE AND THEN LOAD THE FILE DURING THE BOOT THAT YOUR RULES WILL BE LOST.

Comment: On Debian there is no iptables-load, but iptables-restore `iptables-restore < myfile` // https://wiki.debian.org/iptables