# connect timed out

Tags: jax-ws, connection-timeout

I am trying to setup a scenario for a JAXWS web service in which I want the service to timeout (i.e. a connection timeout) so that I can set the proper connection switches during the initial call.

Can anyone tell me a way to setup such a test in a Java EE environment.

Comment: What is the App Server, or better, what is the JAX-WS runtime?

Comment: Does that matter, anyway I am looking for weblogic 10 & JAXWS 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I did it by setting up a proxy that can be used to remove a path from the said machine to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197405/iptables-remove-specific-rules) helped.