# Restrict selenium 2 port - localhost only - no external IP access

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firewall

I have a headless setup in a VPS where selenium server can run - without X server. However, the selenium port is accessible via port 444 across the internet.

Is it possible so that only localhost:4444 is only allowed and external access is not allowed? Be it selenium command line option or firewall/ip table option.

I usually let the port 4444 open like 2-3 hours while doing testing and I'm afraid of being attacked on that port.

I'm using selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar and behat+mink.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this would do: [SO question 7423309](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423309/iptables-block-access-to-port-8000-except-from-ip-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not trying to close port on WAN interface using iptables or equivalent ?
If you and only you, need to access it using internet, consider setup a VPN.

Comment: This is what I'm using and it works so far, so yes, it is using iptables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423309/iptables-block-access-to-port-8000-except-from-ip-address