# How to restrict access to Selenium from ethernet?

Tags: selenium, selenium-server

I have Selenium server listening to 4444 port. How can I make selenium listen to connection only from localhost but not from the whole internet?

Or is there any other way to secure Selenium?

My selenium server is run with such parameters:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -p 4444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that is out of the scope of the application itself, you could place your Selenium server behind a reverse proxy (e.g., Apache Web Server) and just allow local connections to it or just configure your OS's firewall.

Comment: Oh, Selenium just doesn't have such a config parameter and I need to do this with iptables, do I?

Comment: I would say so, there's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206491/restrict-selenium-2-port-localhost-only-no-external-ip-access